# Mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` returns `QueryWithHelpers` instead of result

Tags: node.js, mongoose, findoneandupdate

I have the following invocation.

```js
  static findOneAndUpdate(
    filter: FilterQuery<ISyncedOrder>,
    update: UpdateQuery<ISyncedOrder>
  ): Promise<ISyncedOrder> {
    return SyncedOrders.findOneAndUpdate(
      filter,
      update,
      {upsert: true}
    );
  }
```

According to documents, I should be getting a document. But, IDE shows an error of a type mismatch (screenshot below).

[image]

When I checked the node module, I see the following signature for the method `findOneAndUpdate`.

[image]

What am I missing? Looks like I am headed in a wrong direction.

Comment: [_"Queries are not promises"_](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises).

Comment: @robertklep damn! Didn't notice the need for `exec()`. What do you reckon? Should I keep this question?

Comment: I'll post a proper answer, I think it's still a useful question. The combination between Mongoose's Query instances and TypeScript, and the resulting error, could make life easier for others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because [*"Mongoose queries are not promises"*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises).

They support *just* enough to be used as one (it's a ["thenable"](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/thenable)), but not enough to fool TypeScript into believing it's actually a promise.

The Mongoose documentation also suggests how to get a *real* promise: by using `Query.exec()`:

```
return SyncedOrders.findOneAndUpdate(
  filter,
  update,
  {upsert: true}
).exec();
```

Comment: So it's closed. This answer will complement the missing part in the [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html). Thanks Robert..